# Watir - how do I access a Material-UI Dropdown menu component?

Tags: ruby, watir, material-ui

```
<div style="color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87); height: 56px; line-height: 56px; overflow: hidden; opacity: 1; position: relative; padding-left: 24px; padding-right: 56px; text-overflow: ellipsis; top: 0px; white-space: nowrap;">Never</div>
```

With the HTML listed I am trying to access the dropdown list example on the www.material-UI.com website. I have tried both of the following:

```
b.div(:text => "Never").click

b.span(:text => "Never").click
```

But it does not click on the component to open up the rest of the menu. this is my first week using Watir and I need to use it to automate a web app built using React.js and Material-UI. I have been successful with text boxes and scrolling and even clicking on images but menus and lists are proving problematic.

Comment: Can you provide the url? I don't see the element with `Never` text on it.

Comment: Interesting.  `b.div(:text => "Weekends", :visible => true).click` clicks the right option for the Open Immediate example on http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/dropdown-menu.  But `b.div(:text => "Never", :visible => true).click` throws a "not clickable at point" error.

Comment: Neither of those options did anything for me at all although the second example did throw the "not clickable at point" error that you recieved.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going off of @orde's suggestion that the page in question is http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/dropdown-menu. The solution below worked for me on that page.

To open the entire menu in the "Simple example" section, you can click the button:

```
b.div(:text, 'Never').parent.button.click
```

But I'm not sure what issue you were having. Was it that the menu simply wouldn't open, or that you couldn't open the correct menu because there are multiple menus on the page with "Never" in the contents?

If the problem is the latter, then you can specify which part of the page you want to be in by honing in on the section heading. It's a bit more verbose, but

```
b.span(:text, 'Open Immediate example').parent.parent.parent.parent.parent.buttons[1].click
```

opens the second "Never" menu on the screen. (Five parents above the "Open Immediate example" text gets you to the entire div, and the second button--which has an index of 1--is the drop-down you want. Changing the text to "Simple example" will open the same menu as my first code sample above.)

Comment: Yes you have the right page and it is the menu in the  "Simple example" Dropdown section.. Neither of those examples you specified work for me. And no menu on the page gets opened either. I am at a loss of what to try next.

Comment: Hmm. Not sure what to tell you. It definitely worked for me. I'm using Linux Mint 17.3, Chrome 58, ChromeDriver 2.29, Watir 6.2.0, and Selenium-Webdriver 3.2.1. And I should probably add that `b.div(:text, 'Never').click`, the code that caused you problems initially, works on my system, too.

Comment: Im running OSX 10.11.6, Chrome 58, Chromedriver 2.29, Selenium-Webdriver 3.4, Watir 6.2.1

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that what you want is nested in multiple text nodes, in this case `div` tags. So getting an `ElementCollection` gets both the parent and the child div.
So you can do:

```
browser.div(text: 'Never').child.click
```

or

```
browser.div(text: 'Never', index: 1).click
```

Comment: No luck with either of these.

Comment: Oh, weird, it is like it doesn't register the rest of the page existing before the OS makes it the active window. I got it to work by doing this after navigating there: `browser.div.next_sibling(tag_name: 'div').click`